# Waypoints limit [here-api]

Tags: here-api

Can't find any information in the documentation, what's the waypoints limit for routing requests with HERE-API?

The only thing I could find is: 
List of waypoints that define a route. The first element marks the start, the last the end point. Waypoints in between are interpreted as via points.
Two or more waypoints (waypoint0 and waypoint1, to waypointN)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also you didn't mention the platform (web, mobile) you are using, there are no limits (on mobile limit was removed with SDK 3.6, on web there was never one).

Anyway, as more waypoints you add, as longer calculation takes, and it might result in timeouts. 
I'd suggest to keep care about everything >500 waypoints, especially if the distances in between are a bit longer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I'm using the Web platform.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile SDKs there is a recommendation of 128 waypoints. I tried to use much more and it worked. But the documentation says that it may not always return the route.